# Vistas en SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

Buenas tardes tengo una lista en sharepoint de aproximadamente 10.000 registros, quiero filtrarla por el un campo en común y el resultado de este filtro crearlo como una vista que a su vez quiero darle acceso a ciertos usuarios, la idea que esos usuarios solo puedan ver esos registros filtrados y no puedan quitar el filtro, alguien sabe si puedo hacer esto?, en el caso que se puede realizar este tipo de vistas me podrían por favor indicar como puedo hacerlo?

Comment: Hola Omar, como está formulada tu pregunta, solo puede recibir un "si" o un "no" como respuesta, te sugiero que la edites para hacerla m{as concreta y específica, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que sea eliminada.

aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!.